# I want to Add comment by using Ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel

So here is my code for ajax

i think the ajax code is right .

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.add-comment').click(function(){
var comment_data = $('.comment-form').serialize();


$.ajax ({
headers: {
  'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
},

method: 'POST',
url: '/comment',
data: comment_data,

success: function(data) {
  console.log(data);
  $('.all-comment').append(data);
},
error: function(data) {
  console.log('error');
}
})
})

});
```

here is my controller

```
  public function store(Request $reqeust) {

  $comment = Comment::create([

    'body' => request('body'),

  ]);

  return view('welcome',compact('comment'))->render();


}
```

i think the problem is in controller  btw i am new in development so .. yeah

and yes i am getting error

POST http://localhost:8000/comment 500 (Internal Server Error)

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing an AJAX call, you probably don't need to return the whole welcome view. What's easiest is to return true if the comment was successfully saved, otherwise false.

Also, you aren't attaching your comment to anything. I'm guessing you have other fields that need to be filled in on the comments table, such as post_id. If that is the case, you can pass the post_id as another parameter with the request and do:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $post = Post::findOrFail( $request->post_id );

    Comment::create([
        'post_id'  => $post->id,
        'body'      => $request->body
    ]);

    return true;
}
```

This verifies that there really is a post to link to.

Better yet, you can use Route Model Binding and relationships to do:

```
public function store(Request $request, Post $post)
{
    $post->comments->create([
        'body' => $request->body
    ]);

    return true;
}
```

This will do the same thing and it's a bit cleaner. Also, it will automatically add the post_id because of the relationship (assuming you set that up).